# NPM Declare dependency that would be needed in development by dependents

Tags: npm, dependency-management

I've written an [npm package](https://github.com/raisely/sequelize-to-json-schema) that also supplies a helper function for use in development to simplify writing tests.

That helper function depends on a chai-shallow-deep-equal.

ie, let's say I have `my-project`, which depends on `my-library` for production.
`my-library` supplies a helper for development that relies on `chai-shallow-deep-equal`.

So the dependency tree looks like:

```
// in production
my-project
└─ my-library
   └─ chai-shallow-deep-equal

// in development
my-project
└─ my-library
```

My understanding is, I don't want to declare `chai-shallow-deep-equal` as a normal dependency of `my-library`, because then the developer of `my-project` would get `chai-shallow-deep-equal` in production, but if I declared it as a devDependency, then `chai-shallow-deep-equal` would not be installed for the author of `my-project` in development and so their tests that relied on the helper in `my-library` would fail.

Is that correct?

Is there a solution to this? Or do I need to break out the helper into a separate library?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a sensible answer to this, so ended up breaking the test helper into a separate package.